# Get the value corresponding to a key in the properties of a TinkerVertex

Tags: java, groovy, graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

In Gremlin-Groovy, given a [TinkerVertex](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/tinkergraph/structure/TinkerVertexProperty.html) object, what is the clearest/fastest way to retrieve the value corresponding to a key in its properties, returning a default value if it is not present (such as `null`)?

This is how I am currently doing it:

```
def eval(vertex, field) {
    prop = vertex.property(field)
    prop.isPresent() ? prop.value() : null
}
```

When the vertex doesn't have the desired field `vertex.property(field).value()`yields an exception, so I had to add that condition.

Even if it is kind of short, this operation is done all the time and it bugs me that I haven't found any more "gremlinish" solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A shorter version of what you've done is this:

```
vertex.property(field).orElse(null)
```

`orElse(default)` will return the value if it's present, otherwise the provided default value.